# Excel VBA: How to group rows based on database name and add value based on specific group name?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database in the sheet called "Database" as below: Column A refers to the specific type of data and B refers to the group. For example, X-1 is part of X so it's grouped as X and so forth.

**Sheet "Database"**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| X-1 | X |
| X-2 | X |
| X-3 | X |
| X-4 | X |
| Y-1 | Y |
| Y-2 | Y |
| Y-3 | Y |
| Z-1 | Z |
| Z-2 | Z |
| Z-3 | Z |

Next, I have another set of tables in the "Tables" sheet. So far, only columns A, B, and C exist, but I want to fill in the values in column D and E using the database dictionary above. Column A is the type of data, B is the block number, and C is the value of A. D will be the group of column A and E will be the sum of all data in for each group within that block number.

**Sheet "Table"**

```
| A | B | C |D|E
|:---- |:------:| -----:| -----:| -----:|
| X-1  |  Block 1    | 50 ||
| X-2  | Block 1    | 10 ||
| X-3  | Block 1    | 35 ||
| Y-1  | Block 1    | 45 ||
| Z-1  | Block 1    | 15 ||
| Y-2  | Block 1    | 5 ||
| X-4  | Block 1    | 50 ||
|  | Block 1 Total    | 210 |
```

I ultimately want to make my tables look like the below. It's important that the group data in column D comes at the beginning. Also, please note that sometimes the data in A are not in order. For example, Y-2 comes after Z-1.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X-1 | Block 1 | 50 | X | 145 |
| X-2 | Block 1 | 10 |  |  |
| X-3 | Block 1 | 35 |  |  |
| Y-1 | Block 1 | 45 | Y | 50 |
| Z-1 | Block 1 | 15 | Z | 15 |
| Y-2 | Block 1 | 5 |  |  |
| X-4 | Block 1 | 50 |  |  |
|  | Block 1 Total | 210 |  |  |

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X-1 | Block 2 | 10 | X | 80 |
| X-2 | Block 2 | 70 |  |  |
| Y-1 | Block 2 | 15 | Y | 20 |
| Y-2 | Block 2 | 5 |  |  |
| Z-1 | Block 2 | 100 | Z | 600 |
| Z-2 | Block 2 | 200 |  |  |
| Z-3 | Block 2 | 300 |  |  |
|  | Block 2 Total | 700 |  |  |

So far my script looks like this:

```
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i, J, K As Integer
    Dim NumRows As Integer
    
    lastrow = Worksheets("Table").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    NumRows = Worksheets("Database").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    
    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    
            FundName_T = Worksheets("Table").Range("A" & i).Value
    
            For K = 2 To NumRows
                FundName_D = Worksheets("Database").Range("A" & K).Value
        
        If Cells(i, "A") <> "" And FundName_T = FundName_D Then
            GroupName = Worksheets("Database").Range("B" & K).Value
            Cells(i, "H") = GroupName
    
        End If
    
            Next K
    Next i
```

The above will make the table look like this:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X-1 | Block 2 | 10 | X |  |
| X-2 | Block 2 | 70 | X |  |
| Y-1 | Block 2 | 15 | Y |  |
| Y-2 | Block 2 | 5 | Y |  |
| Z-1 | Block 2 | 100 | Z |  |
| Z-2 | Block 2 | 200 | Z |  |
| Z-3 | Block 2 | 300 | Z |  |
|  | Block 2 Total | 700 |  |  |

Can someone please help?

Comment: Block 1 is not sorted, but block 2 is. Is that just an effect from the table, or do you want the macro to do any sorting?

Comment: Do you want your output as separate tables for each Block?  Or do you want everything combined into one table sorted by Block?

Comment: Hello Ron, thanks for the reply. I would like the macro to combine into one table sorted by block. Sorry I wasn't clear. Block 1 and Block 2 look like they're separate tables but it's actually one table. I just separated them so it's easier to explain. There's actually hundreds of blocks. Please also keep in mind that there's always a blank in column A whenever you see a "Block # total."

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the reply. Column A in the table isn't sorted, and that's the effect from the table. Sorry for the confusion, but as explained to Ron, block 1 and block 2 are actually one big table. I just separated them so it's easier to explain. There's actually hundreds of blocks within one table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

- Ensure your data is in "Tables" and that you have the Names of those tables

  - I assumed, as you show, that your Table columns do not have headers.
  - That being the case, the system will add headers with names like `Column n`
- Select some cell in one of the tables and `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor` and paste the **M Code** below into that window
- Replace the table names in Lines 2 and 3 of the code with the appropriate names for your tables on your `Database` and `Table` sheets (*and the order is important*)
- Examine the `Applied Steps` window and the comments to understand the methodology.

**M Code**

```
let

//Change table names to your actual table names
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Database"]}[Content],
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],

//Remove Block Totals
//It will be easier to just calculate them later
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source2, each ([Column1] <> null and [Column1] <> "")),

//Join with Group Column to match up with Column1
//then expand the nested join
    grpCol = Table.AddJoinColumn(#"Filtered Rows","Column1",Source,"Column1","with Group"),
    #"Expanded with Group" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(grpCol, "with Group", {"Column2"}, {"with Group.Column2"}),

//Rename columns for clarity
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded with Group",{
        {"Column1", "Part"}, 
        {"Column2", "Block"}, 
        {"Column3", "Units"}, 
        {"with Group.Column2", "Group"}
        }),

//Group by "Block" and "Group"
//Calculate Subtotal for each Group (within each Block)
//Add Index column to subTable -- to be used so Group Name and Total for group only appear on first line
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"Block", "Group"}, {
            {"Amt", each List.Sum([Units]), type number}, 
            {"All", each _, type table [Part=text, Block=text, Units=number, Group=text]},
            {"Idx", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Index",0,1)}
            }),

//Remove unneeded column of tables and Expand the column of tables with Index column added
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"All"}),
    #"Expanded Idx" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Idx", {"Part", "Units", "Index"}, {"Part", "Units", "Index"}),

//Add columns for Group and Group Total, showing only on the first entry of the Group Name
//then remove unneeded columns
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Idx", "Group.1", each if [Index] = 0 then [Group] else null),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Group Total", each if [Index] = 0 then [Amt] else null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Group", "Amt", "Index"}),

#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Group.1", "Group"}}),

//Group by Block
//Add Block subtotal row to each block group
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Block"}, {
        {"blockGroup", each _, type table [Block=text, Part=text, Units=number, Group=nullable text, Group Total=nullable number]},
        {"Block Total", each Table.InsertRows(_, Table.RowCount(_),
            {[Block=null, Part=[Block]{0} & " Total", Units=List.Sum([Units]), Group=null,Group Total=null]})}       
        }),

//Remove unneeded column and expand the table
    #"Removed Columns3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows1",{"blockGroup", "Block"}),
    #"Expanded Block Total" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns3", "Block Total", {"Block", "Part", "Units", "Group", "Group Total"}, {"Block", "Part", "Units", "Group", "Group Total"})
in
    #"Expanded Block Total"
```

**Database**

[image]

**Table**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

*If you require the Results **Part** column to be sorted in the same order as the original table, that can be done, but would require extra steps*

Comment: Hello Ron! Thank you so much! This is great. I've never used Power Query before so this is a great occasion. Curious, is what I'm trying to do impossible via VBA? I prefer VBA because I can just add to what I already have written so far...

Comment: @Korosuke Oh, it can be done in VBA. But if I were doing it in VBA, your existing code would not be my approach (so there would be nothing to add to what you have). I would be working entirely with VBA arrays instead of having multiple calls to/from the worksheet.  I would create a Class object with the information for each Block (collections of groups, parts and units), and collecting these objects in a Dictionary. It would execute much faster than the process you have laid out, and should be easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for the quick reply. I tried your advice in VBA, but can't seem to make it work. As I need further studying on dictionaries and arrays, can you please help a newbie out?

Comment: @Korosuke You will find the late Chip Pearson's web site an invaluable resource. For your specific issues, I suggest the topics on [Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) and this introductory article on  [Clases in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx).  But there is much more there that will be useful to you.